# how to offset squares in a loop?

Tags: processing

I'm creating a sketch of the cafe wall illusion and need help coming up with a way to offset the checkerboard effect in Processing. The row below the previous one cannot be too close to the the row above it. basically I need it too look offset by half a tile each row going down but random starting points.

```java
void setup(){
    size (500, 500);
    strokeWeight(3);
    stroke(127);
    tileSize = height/ROW_NUM;
    drawTiles();
}

void draw() {
}

void drawTiles() {
    for (int i=0; i<ROW_NUM; i++) {
        squareX = int(random(-tileSize, 0)); 

        int counter = 0;
        while (squareX < width) {

            if (counter%2==0) {
                fill(0);
                rect(squareX, squareY, tileSize, tileSize);
            } else {
                fill(255);
                rect(squareX, squareY, tileSize, tileSize);
            }
            squareX += tileSize;
            counter ++;
        }
        squareY += tileSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this actually Java code? @Rabbid76 (the editor) might have added the tag mistakenly.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but this is completely unclear. I've no idea what you're asking about. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) respectively [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve your question.

Comment: @Marcono1234 This is java please read the tag info of <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. "Processing" is based on java and [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Sorry this is my first time using this site. Im not sure how i can post a picture of what my code is outputting. I can try and add some comments to the code if that helps.

Comment: Overall what you have already is not that bad, you could play with other random functions like [noise()](https://processing.org/reference/noise_.html) or [randomGaussian()](https://processing.org/reference/randomGaussian_.html)

Comment: @Rabbid76 on a technical note: Processing is _based on_ but is not _the same as_ java. Processing is "java, if java only had a single class to work with", which fundamentally changes the rules around visibility and scope resolution. It uses identical syntax, but does _not_ have identical execution behaviour for seemingly similar code between the two, because of the intermediate form it gets assembled to prior to class compilation.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So what is the issue? In my comment I said *"based on"*. "Processing" is for novice to learn programming, with the use of Java syntax or an other language if it is provided by an plugin (e.g. python or JavaScript)

Comment: The issue is adding the "java" tag. This isn't Java. It's very close to java, but tagging it as such just invites contributions by people watching the java tag. Also, I think if you ask Ben or Casey they will tell you it's not "for novices" but for people who _just_ want to do visual programming. I'm a senior engineer, with 8 years of java experience before I ever used Processing, and yet I _still_ fire up Processing when I need a data or maths visualisation without any of the nonsense that a full programming language requires me to add on top. Processing is a tool for narrow use-case.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I see your point, but I disagree. Processing has plug-ins for multiple languages, so the [tag:java] tag is an important additional information. At least the syntax is java. "processing" is misleading and often understood more general than it is. I've often seen question tagged [tag:processing] only, which have been down-voted immediately, because of the "missing" language tag. By the way, there are > 1.600.000 java questions. No one searches for java only. It is possible to add 5 tags and that should be used to specify the question.

Comment: And in all those cases it's up to _us_ as members of the SO community to point out that Processing is a language, and that the tag for it literally tells you so, so that all those folks who removed the tag learn something and won't do it again in the future, too. And if that bothers you, suggest a rename (e.g. "processing-lang" or something). Also, `java` is one of the tags I actively watch. Claiming no one watches it, when it's super easy to see how many folks watch a tag, is a little bit selective blindness: there are 1.3 _million_ people watching that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than figuring out how to move the coordinates for your rectangles, "move the coordinate system" by using [translate](http://processingjs.org/reference/translate_/):

```java
final int rectSize = ...

void setup() {
    ...
    noLoop();
    strokeWeight(4);
    stroke(127);
}
```

In draw, rather than figuring out x/y coordinates for each rect, instead we "draw a row of tiles" starting at (0,0), and then we *change what (0,0) means* by using `translate`, by moving it down one row and either right or left by a little depending on which row we're at; we want to move right for row 1 and 2, then left for row 3 and 4, then right for 5 and 6, etc. so we want to move left if (row number/2) rounds to an even number, and right if it rounds to an odd number.

```java
void draw() {
  int steps = 4;
  for(int row=0; row < 1 + height/rectSize; row++) {
    drawTileRow();
    int step = rectSize / steps;
    if ((row / 2) % 2 == 0) {
      step = -step;
    }
    translate(step, rectSize);
  }
}
```

You can then write much simpler code in the drawTileRow function, just drawing rects starting at (0,0) and ending at (width,0), although you really want to start at `-rectSize`, and end at `width+rectSize`, to compensate for the fact that the entire global coordinate system gets offset:

```java
void drawTileRow() {
  boolean negative = false;
  for(int x=-rectSize; x<width+rectSize; x+=rectSize) {
    fill(negative ? 255 : 0);
    rect(x,0,rectSize,rectSize);
    negative = !negative;
  }
}
```

The result is properly trippy.

[image]